# Wordpress: Show pages of only certain authors

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make it so that I can go to the pages of only certain authors, and a redirect will work for the rest. I'm trying to do this through is_author, but it does not accept meta arguments, and does not understand != Perhaps someone knows how to solve this problem. Thank you!

i tried this in function.php :

```
function redirect_author_page() {
    global $wp_query;
    
    if (is_author($author != array('name1', 'name2'))) {
        wp_safe_redirect(get_option('home'), 301); 
        exit; 
    }
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_author_page');
```

Answer (score 0):

According to an example in the docs of the function [`is_author`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_author/#user-contributed-notes)

```php
if (is_author(array('name1', 'name2'))) {
  // do this
} else {
  // do that
}
```

Comment: I'll try this:
   
 if (is_author(array('name1', 'name2'))) {
        print(" ");
    } else {
        wp_safe_redirect(get_option('home'), 301); 
        exit; 
    }
}
but have "Circular redirection on a page"

Comment: so it's working :-) but you should only redirect if you're on the right condition. something like `if (is_author()... && !is_home())`

Comment: yes, it works, but not quite as we would like. in this case i will have to write a lot of && ! is_front_page && ! is_single && ! is_account_page and so on

Comment: you can try the opposite condition, and redirect only if not.

Answer (score 0):

!= means not equal, but doesn't work in this instance. If you wanted to use it in the case of is_author() you'd add the 'not' at the beginning. You also need a comma separating the parameters.

```
if (!is_author($author, array('name1', 'name2')) && !is_home()) {
    wp_safe_redirect(get_option('home'), 301); 
    exit; 
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but also got the error "cyclic redirect on page"

Comment: That may mean the author of the homepage doesn't meet the requirements of the redirect either. You say "only go to the pages of certain authors," which means in your condition, the homepage author isn't one of those "certain authors" either. I have addended the above answer to account for the homepage.

Comment: Also, make sure you're clear on front page vs blog homepage, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30385/when-to-use-is-home-vs-is-front-page

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be this:

function redirect_author_page() {
global $wp_query;

```
global $authordata;

$author_roles = $authordata->roles;
$author_role = array_shift($author_roles);


if ( is_author($author_role != 'role_name' )) {
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header( 404 );
    get_template_part( 404 ); 
    exit();
}
```

The required authors were assigned a certain role, and then for all roles that are not equal to it, a 404 page is displayed (or whatever you need, but in the example, a 404 page). Marsellus and IT Goldman, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like this:

```
function redirect_author_page() {
    global $wp_query;
    
    if (!is_author(array('name1', 'name2')) && is_single()) {
        wp_safe_redirect(get_option('home'), 301); 
        exit; 
    }
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_author_page');
```